# Poor $lookup/$sort performance on small collections WITH indexes

Tags: mongodb, lookup

I've gone through almost 10 similar posts here on SO, and I'm still confused with the results I am getting: 5+ seconds for a sort on a foreign field on a single $lookup aggregation between a 42K document collection and a 19 record collection. Aka, total cross product of 798K.

Unfortunately, denormalization is not a great option here as the documents in the 'to' collection are heavily shared and would require a massive amount of updates across the database when changes are made.

That being said, I can't seem to understand why the following would take this long regardless. I feel like I must be doing something wrong.

The context:

1. A 4 vCPU, 16 GB RAM VM is running Debian 10 / MongoDB 4.4 as a single node replica set and nothing
   else. Fully updated .NET MongoDB driver (I just updated a moment ago and re-tested)
2. There is one lookup in the aggregation, with the 'from' collection
   having 42K documents, and the 'to' collection having 19 documents.
3. All aggregations, indexes, and collections are using default collation.
4. The foreign field in the 'to' collection has an index. Yes, just for those 19 records in case it would make a difference.
5. One of the posts regarding slow $lookup performance, mentioned that if $eq was not used within the nested pipeline of the $lookup stage, it wouldn't use the index. So I made sure that the aggregation pipeline used an $eq operator.

Here's the pipeline:

```
[{ "$lookup" : 
    { "from" : "4", 
    "let" : { "key" : "$1" }, 
    "pipeline" : 
        [{ "$match" : 
            { "$expr" : 
                { "$eq" : ["$id", { "$substrCP" : ["$$key", 0, { "$indexOfCP" : ["$$key", "_"] }] }] } } }, 
        { "$unwind" : { "path" : "$RF2" } }, 
        { "$match" : { "$expr" : { "$eq" : ["$RF2.id", "$$key"] } } }, 
        { "$replaceRoot" : { "newRoot" : "$RF2" } }], 
    "as" : "L1" } }, 
{ "$sort" : { "L1.5" : 1 } },
{ "$project" : { "L1" : 0 } }, 
{ "$limit" : 100 }]
```

Taking out the nested $unwind/$match/$replaceRoot combo takes away about 30% of the run time bringing it down to 3.5 seconds, however, those stages are necessary to link/lookup to the proper sub document.  Sorts on the 'from' collection with no lookup required are done within 0.5 seconds.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I've just tested the same thing with a larger set of records (38K records in the 'from' collection, 26K records in the 'to' collection, one-to-one relationship). Took over 7 minutes to complete the sort. I checked in Compass and saw that the index on "id" was actually being used (kept refreshing during the 7 minutes and saw it rise, I'm currently the only user of the database).

Here's the pipeline, which is simpler than the first:

```
[{ "$lookup" : 
    { "from" : "1007", 
    "let" : { "key" : "$13" }, 
    "pipeline" : 
        [{ "$match" : 
            { "$expr" : { "$eq" : ["$id", "$$key"] } } }], 
    "as" : "L1" } }, 
{ "$sort" : { "L1.1" : -1 } }, 
{ "$project" : { "L1" : 0 } }, 
{ "$limit" : 100 }]
```

Does 7 minutes sound reasonable given the above info?

Edit 2:

shell code to create two 40k record collections (prod and prod2) with two fields (name: string, uid: integer):

```
var randomName = function() { 
    return (Math.random()+1).toString(36).substring(2); 
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 40000; ++i) { 
    db.test.insert({ 
        name: randomName(), 
        uid: i }); 
}
```

I created an index on the 'uid' field on prod2, increased the sample document limit of Compass to 50k, then did just the following lookup, which took two full minutes to compute:

```
{ from: 'prod2', 
localField: 'uid', 
foreignField: 'uid', 
as: 'test' }
```

Edit 3:

I've just also ran the aggregation pipeline directly from the shell and got results within a few seconds instead of two minutes:

```
db.test1.aggregate([{ $lookup:
{ from: 'test2', 
  localField: 'uid', 
  foreignField: 'uid', 
  as: 'test' } }]).toArray()
```

What's causing the discrepancy between the shell and both Compass and the .NET driver?

Comment: I would start with a simple find all for one collection, then do a basic $lookup, and compare those times.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I dissected that second aggregation in Compass and found that the $lookup is actually quick. It's the $sort alone that is taking 7 minutes. Would it be proper form to make another post regarding the speed issue with $sort or simply edit the question in-place?

Comment: Use of indexes for sorting is covered in documentation. If you are sorting on the fields from joined collections you may need to reorganize the pipeline to query those first.

Comment: Sorting the L1.1 equivalent field directly on the collection, which has no index, takes a split second for 26.4k documents. After the $lookup stage in the second pipeline above, the aggregation pipeline has a total of 38.4k documents and a total size of roughly 13MB, well within the 100MB sort-in-memory limit. Why the massive discrepancy (half a second vs. 7 minutes) in sort time when in both situations, there is no index and the full set of documents fits nicely in memory? Considering the size and count of the in-aggregation set of documents, why would that ever take more than a few seconds?

Comment: Doing the above sort in a .NET application with a single thread in an attached-debug context would still run circles around that 7 minute figure. That's what I can't wrap my head around and what makes me think there's something wrong here.

Comment: I suggest 1) simplifying your queries further and making them more readable and 2) providing mongo shell code to generate and insert sample data that would reproduce your results.

Comment: Will do. An fyi, I did make a mistake in my first comment. Compass automatically imposes of $limit of 20, which is what made the $lookup stage look fast ($sort is forced to look at all documents regardless). So I was incorrect in saying the $sort is the cause of the slow down, the $lookup stage took the 7 minutes when telling compass to impose a limit larger than the collection size.

Comment: shell code to create two 40k record collections (prod and prod2) with two fields (name: string, uid: integer):

var randomName = function() {
  return (Math.random()+1).toString(36).substring(2);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 40000; ++i) {
  db.test.insert({
      name: randomName(),
      uid: i
  });
}

I created an index on the 'uid' field on prod2, increased the sample document limit of compass to 50k, then did just the following lookup, which took two full minutes to compute:

{
from: 'prod2',
localField: 'uid',
foreignField: 'uid',
as: 'test'
}

Comment: I did have the above well-formatted, but it seems that SO wanted to auto-format it anyway.

Comment: Can you update the question with the data & the shell query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this post, the following worked for me: Using the localField/foreignField version of the $lookup operator.

When monitoring the index in Compass, both the let/pipeline and the localField/foreignField versions hit the appropriate index but was orders of magnitude slower when using the let/pipeline version.

I restructured my query building logic to only use localField/foreignField and it has made a world of difference.